# Constrained minimization of an expectation with regards to a function

Tags: probability, optimization

Let us assume that we have a continuous random variable $q \in \left(0, +\infty \right)$ which follows a known probability distribution $f\left(q\right)$. We also have a deterministic but unknown function $s\left(q\right)$ and a deterministic and known function $P\left(s\right) \in \left(0, 1 \right)$

I need to solve the following optimisation problem:

$$
\max_{s} \hspace{0.3cm} \mathcal{E}\left\{ P\left(s \left( q\right)\right) s\left(q\right) q \right\} \hspace{0.1cm} \text{ s.t. } \hspace{0.1cm} \mathcal{E}\left\{ P\left(s \left( q\right)\right) \right\} \gt C > 0 \text{ and } s\left(q\right) \in \left(0, 1\right)
$$

I am not familiar with optimisation with respect to functions, so any help with this or just pointers to a general area of study would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the general topic of *functional analysis.* However, the specific problem is so trivial that I suspect you might not have correctly communicated it.  Since $s$ is arbitrary, pick any constant $N \gt 0$ and define $s(q)=-N/q$ provided $q\ne 0$ and otherwise $s(q)=0.$ Since the expectation of $s(q)q$ equals $-N\Pr(q\ne 0)=-N,$ obviously this expectation diverges to $-\infty$ as $N$ grows large. A slight modification of this example will conform to the constraint, since $s$ can take on arbitrarily negative values. Which part of this analysis reflects my misunderstanding of the problem?

Comment: You are correct, I am still trying to formulate the problem, to be honest. I have changed the specs a bit and, hopefully, now it will not be trivial.

Comment: Because you're struggling with an unfamiliar subject, might I suggest adopting a different strategy of explaining what the underlying statistical problem is and letting your respondents formulate it mathematically?

Comment: I have a known function $P\left(s\right)$ which gives a probability corresponding to a value of $s$, with $s \in \left(-1, 1\right)$. I want to find a function $s\left( q \right)$ which maps my inputs $q \in \left(0, +\infty \right)$ to $s$ and maximises the expectation given above, with the constraint that the average probability is larger than a thresold $C$. Does this make more sense?